# Moment generating function/integral and derivative

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

For moment generating functions $M_X(t) = E(e^{Xt})$ holds:

$$ M'_X(0)= E(X)$$

For the proof I would do this:
$$ E(X)=E(Xe^{tX})|_{t=0} =E(\frac{d}{dt}e^{tX})|_{t=0} $$
How can I argue for swaping integral and derivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some additional hypothesis for this. If $Ee^{c|X|} <\infty$ for some $c>0$ then you can justify it as follows: $|\frac 1 h \int_0^{h} e^{tX} dt| \leq e^{c|X|}$ whenver $|h| <c$. Writing down the value of this integral we get $|\frac 1 h (e^{hX}-1)| \leq e^{c|X|}$. Now we can apply DCT to finish the proof. It is worth observing that $e^{c|X|} \leq e^{cX}+e^{-cX}$ so if we know that existence of $M_X(c)$ and $M_X(-c)$ that would be enough for this proof.

Answer (score -1):

You need the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: How would apply this on that case?